# Can you link to an HTML file?

Tags: html

My website has the same navigation menu throughout, instead to rewriting the HTML code for every page, can I link to a second HTML file (that contains the nav HTML code) like you would with CSS?  Or will that create problems?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file
? Hope that helps.

Comment: You will probably want a templating framework for this. There are about a million of them. The one I use is Jekyll, though there should be others that are geared towards more beginning users of HTML. Alternatively you could use server-side includes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and link!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple way would be to put the header part in a separate html file.

Now load this file in html code using jQuery `load` function like

```
$("#headerDiv").load("header.html")
```

Know that, this will require web server because load function sends a request to server.

Check out the code sample:

**demo.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(function(){
    $("#headerDiv").load("header.html");
   });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerDiv"></div>
<!-- Rest of the code -->
</body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<div >
    <a>something</a>
    <a>something</a>        
</div>
```

Comment: I would love the code!  Thanks for the server tip...I'm using my computer and it previewing right now.

Comment: @JeffArries check out the code above. That will work fine for you. Let me know if you need further improved answer

Comment: Thanks for the code! I will use that! (once I get a server ;) )

Comment: Is the ajax.googleapis.com script required?  How can I know it is safe?

Comment: How does this method contrast with this one, `<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> `? Which is better?

Comment: @dyllandry w3-include-html AFAIK is provided by w3data.js lib... just anoter JS way to accomplish

Answer (score 5):

for an HTML solution -*since you have no other tags in your question*- there is HTML imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="nav.html">
```

But this new -*working draft*- and it doesn't have good browser support.

---

Resources:

- [W3C - imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/)
- [MDN - HTML Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)
- [caniuse - HTML Imports](http://caniuse.com/#search=import)
- [webcomponents.org - introduction to html imports](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/)
- [html5rocks - imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Comment: Sorry about the lack of tags, I wasn't sure what was needed!  I will probably use a server-side JavaScript/jQuery solution!  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Sure, I've always used server-side for this, also as people suggested using js frameworks

Comment: Do you have any code I could use?  One of the other posts mentioned code but have yet to provide it.  Is there a js framework you recommend?  Or any other suggestions?  I'm new to website design and am open to anything.

Comment: PHP `<?php include_once('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>`, using AngularJS you can do this `<div ng-include="'includes/navbar.html'"></div>` [**`ng-include` example**](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_include)

Comment: Thanks again!  A W3Schools link, I love them!

Answer (score 5):

That is called HTML includes, and **YES**, it is possible

```
<div w3-include-HTML="content.html">My HTML include will go here.</div>
<script>
(function () {
  myHTMLInclude();
  function myHTMLInclude() {
    var z, i, a, file, xhttp;
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      if (z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html")) {
        a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
        file = z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            a.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
            a.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            z[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, z[i]);
            myHTMLInclude();
          }
        }      
        xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
        xhttp.send();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

**NOTES**

HTML doesn't have a simple include mechanism (except for frames like iframe, which have side effects).

A better solution would be to use [Server-Side includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), which is the preferred way of adding common parts to your document, on the server, of course.

Comment: This needs javascript right? like `<script src="w3-include-HTML.js"></script>`??

Comment: Thanks for the code and response!  I will look into Server-Side includes!

Answer (score 0):

W3schools has an include. They also have there own CSS as a side note. Put the callup in footer (wherever)

```
<script src="vendor/w3js.min.js"></script>
<script src="w3.includeHTML();"></script>
```

And then on page:

```
<header class="header navbar-fixed-top">
    <nav id="inc_nav" w3-include-html="nav.html"></nav>
</header>

    <section id="inc_header" w3-include-html="header.html"></section>

    <div id="content" tabindex="-1"></div>
```