# How to make a programming code box in html css bootstrap or angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

**How to make a programming code box in html css bootstrap or angular js**

Comment: Here is the answer which uses jquery
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249951/4874281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [**w3-include**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

    <script>
        w3IncludeHTML();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or [**PHP**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) style

```
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p>Some more text.</p>
        <?php include 'footer.php';?>

    </body>
</html>
```

To complete, here's a [**JQuery**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249827/can-you-link-to-an-html-file/35249951#35249951) style (thanks @Manivannan for the link)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"</script>
        <script> 
            $(function(){
                $("#headerDiv").load("header.html");
            });  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headerDiv"></div>
        <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i dont want to use w3school sir @carl jan

Comment: @shubhamgupta Added php version

Comment: i dont know php @carl jan

Comment: only html or jquer, javascript @carl jan

Comment: Check @Manivannan's answer

Comment: shubam gupta, you don't have to be an expert in php. You just can use the simple include function added by @Carl Jan

Comment: @shubhamgupta There are 3 codes there, what is not working?

Comment: and Sir for that code Manivannan sir had said that we have to use Server ? How ? @CarlJan

Comment: page was not Loading it showing blank sccreen @CarlJan

Comment: If you're in Windows, use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/), and if you are in Linux, use [LAMP](https://www.linux.com/learn/easy-lamp-server-installation)

Comment: I am not having the knowledge of server @CarlJan

Comment: Then start studying them, you will be needing them sooner or later

Comment: is it possible to load without server @CarlJan Sir

Comment: Try the PHP version

Comment: sir shall we communicate with each other on social media like instagram or facebok @CarlJan

Comment: You are very help full please sir @CarlJan